# Ninject Memoize Instances in Singleton Scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm using Ninject to instantiate some objects with a constructor arg passed, e.g.:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string myArg)
    {
        this.myArg = myArg;
    }
}
```

The number of instances I need of this class won't be known until runtime, but what I want to do is ensure that each variation of `myArg` results in a different singleton instance (so asking for the same value twice returns the same instance, but different args return different instances).

Does anyone know of a good, preferably built-in, way of doing this?

I found an article written for an older version of Ninject [How To Ensure One Instance per Variation of Activation Parameters](http://iridescence.no/post/Ninject-and-Singletons-How-To-Ensure-One-Instance-per-Variation-of-Activation-Parameters.aspx) but was hoping there'd be a tidier solution for the newer version.

**Edit**

Here's what I went with, adapted from Akim's answer below:

```
private readonly ConcurrentBag<string> scopeParameters = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

internal object ParameterScope(IContext context, string parameterName)
{
    var param = context.Parameters.First(p => p.Name.Equals(parameterName));
    var paramValue = param.GetValue(context, context.Request.Target) as string;
    paramValue = string.Intern(paramValue);

    if (paramValue != null && !scopeParameters.Contains(paramValue))
    {
        scopeParameters.Add(paramValue);
    }

    return paramValue;
}

public override void Load()
{
    Bind<MyClass>()
            .ToSelf()
            .InScope(c => ParameterScope(c, "myArg"));

    Bind<IMyClassFactory>()
        .ToFactory();
}
```

Comment: Check [`ninject.extensions.factory`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory) for automatic implementation of abstract factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve require behaviour by providing custom scope using `IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> InScope(Func<IContext, object> scope)` method for `MyClass` binding

> Indicates that instances activated via the binding should **be re-used
>   as long as the object returned by the provided callback remains alive**
>   (that is, has not been garbage collected).

So, you need to return value of first constructor argument from `Func<IContext, object> scope`and make sure that [garbage-collector](/questions/tagged/garbage-collector) would not collect it.

Here is a snippet:

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    // stores string myArg to protect from CG
    ConcurrentBag<string> ParamSet = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MyClass>()
            .ToSelf()
            // custom scope
            .InScope((context) =>
                {
                    // get first constructor argument
                    var param = context.Parameters.First().GetValue(context, context.Request.Target) as string;                    

                    // retrieves system reference to string
                    param = string.Intern(param);

                    // protect value from CG
                    if(param != null && ParamSet.Contains(param))
                    {
                        // protect from GC
                        ParamSet.Add(param);
                    }

                    // make Ninject to return same instance for this argument
                    return param;
                });
    }
}
```

ps: [full sample code with unittests](https://gist.github.com/4622557)

Comment: Really like how straightforward this solution is, and I got a bit of extra help on the wiki at https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes. The instances will need to come from a factory though, do you know if this will be compatible with the Factory Extension? I assume it will be.

Comment: Sure it works! See [updated sample with `ninject.extensions.facotry`](https://gist.github.com/4622557)

Comment: I tidied up your example a bit in my code so that I could tell it which parameter to use instead of always using the first one and I wrote some tests. Works perfectly, thanks!!